# WIX JS - Custom Preloader Screen

Tags: javascript, preloader, velo

I have got a site made with wix and I found this code that allows you for a custom preloader screen. It works fine, however it keeps triggering whenever the site is refreshed or you press the back button. Can I make it trigger only once every 10 minutes or once per session? If you have an idea on how to do it would you be kind enough to post your solution? I studied JS but it was long ago and in the end I gave up. Cheers!

```
$w.onReady(() => {
    waitForLoading();
});

export function button6_onClick() {
    $w('#lightbox1').show();
    waitForLoading();
}

function waitForLoading() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        $w('#lightbox1').hide('FadeOut');
    }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: That timeout doesn't wait for the page to load it literally just waits 1500ms, you want to listen to the `load` event on `$("body")`  instead of just having a `setTimeout`

Comment: The time out function hides the preloader screen after 1500ms. An it is triggered on load, isnt it?

Comment: What exactly you mean by `it keeps triggering`? The lightbox appearance or the `waitForLoading`?

Comment: Whenever I refresh the site or press the go backwards button on a browser to go back to the home page the function triggers. Meaning: the section appears as the site loads and disappears after 1500ms. The way I want it to work is for the section to be a welcome screen that you see when you enter the site for the first time during a session. Let's say once per day or once per 10 minutes.

Comment: The behaviour you are seeing makes _perfect sense_ for the code you are writing. My advice is to look for a preloader in the Wix marketplace _or_ to pay a coder to look. Wix also have good support overall - so check with them. Alternatively, if you're up for it I'd read on events and figure out _what_ this code does and what event represents assets loading.

Comment: cheers, I will look into it : )